# Selecting data from a specific table in MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a schema of project with a  table of student_record with attributes of firstname, middlename and lastname.
Now using java, I would like to display in my jTable the lists of students for example that the lastname starts with A. The results will automatically display right after I pressed a key. But I think my codes are not totally correct.,

---

```
public void search()
{

    try{
        String sql = "Select * from project.student_record where lastname like '%search'";
        st = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = st.executeQuery();
        stud.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

-----this is for the textField when I typed a letter

```
 private void searchKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:
            Thread e = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    search();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    };
    {
    }

    e.start();
}
```

Comment: ”*I think my codes are not totally correct.*”
What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Oh, they're not......at least you're correct about that.

Comment: This may not be the main issue, but I noticed you say `WHERE lastname LIKE '%search'` I think you would get better search results if you added the wildcard to the end, or keep one on each end of the `LIKE` clause. For instance `SELECT * FROM student_record WHERE lastname LIKE '%search%'"`

Comment: The 'search' thingy is the variable name of the textfield where i should type any letter., is it right that I put it there???

Comment: The 'search' thingy is the variable name of the textfield where i should type any letter., is it right that I put it there??

Answer (score 0):

If 'search' would typically be the first letter of the  last name, your wild card (%) should only be at the end of LIKE clause, not at the beginning at all.  If you leave it at the beginning and I type the letter "M" for the search term, it would then return all results that have M either in the first character position or anywhere else in the string.

```
SELECT * FROM student_record WHERE lastname LIKE 'search%'"
```

The above will require that the user's search term is at the beginning of the string and will match any subsequent characters in the lastname field.

Comment: @InformationTechnology if lastname is indexed in MySQL and you use LIKE '%search%'  MySQL will still use an FULL table scan to find the records..  if you use  LIKE 'search%' MySQL can and will use an index if there is one on lastname if there is no index on lastname an FULL table is still required.

Comment: That's because using '%search%' means if search = "m" it would match results such as "Manson" or "Flame" because of the m.  This requires a full text search, while not allowing the first character(s) to be variable allows the engine to take advantage of the index.

Comment: I HAVE A PROBLEM AGAIN., I DO HAVE 2 RECORDS ON TEH STUDENT_RECORD, WHEN I TRY TO LOOK FOR THE LASTNAME THAT STARTS WITH 'SOME LETTER', NOTHING WILL BE DISPLAYED ON THE TABLE LIST. ALL THE RECORDS WILL DISAPPEAR. I THINK I ALREADY GOT THE CODES RIGHT, ITS JUST THAT NOTHING WILL BE DISPLAYED. AND ALL THE RECORDS SHOULD BE DISPLAYED AGAIN WHENEVER I DELETE THE 'SOMELETTER' ON THE TEXTFIELD